# If there have a dice game. What is the probability that a player will win the game?

Tags: probability, dice

1. Consider 2 person play (player A and B) the dice game. Both of them has 3 six-sided dices.
2. They roll it together. If the die lands 1, take it out, if the die land 6, give it to others. [Exm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPuPX.jpg)
3. In one round, who left the least dice, who will win the game
4. Then what is the probability that player A will win the game? (If both of them left the same amount of dice, then is tie)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. PLease read about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Now I am having to set a new game, and get the probability myself. This is the game that I have thing about, but I don't know how to cal the probability. Does the question have any problem??

Comment: Just work out the probability of a tie (the answer is then half the probability that there isn't a tie).  To get a tie there are only a few cases:  nobody throws a $1$ or a $6$ or they do throw $1's$ or $6's$ but those throws cancel out.  Just work out each case by hand.

Comment: I make it $0.3836162551440329$

Comment: How to get 0.3836162551440329?

Comment: Ok, I will try to get the probability of tie

Comment: Just to be clear, in the example, the player on the left (presumably Player A) is left with two dice, while the player on the right is left with three, and consequently the player on the left wins the game, right?

Comment: In determining who wins the game, I just want to make sure: We count the number of dice, right?  Not the number of pips (dots), is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the least dice left will win the game, count the number of dice

Comment: The example is right